# very simple wordpress related error

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I saw one wordpress theme. Assume theme's demo available at domain1.com, I like it and I collected that demo files and theme files.

Then i installed wordpress manully into a server, after that I imported demo content and theme. And everything looks working nice.

Assume domain2.com is the new url in which I installed wordpress. The imported demo content have an `about` menu button. Current when i click on that it goes to domain1's about section. So i went to Appearance> Menus and found About menu item and its url containing following `#!/about_section`

So my question is why the system is going go domain1.com/#!/about_section instead of domain2.com/#!/about_section? and what setting i should edit to fix this problem?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the website's URL. When I move a WordPress website to a different address i just export the database and within the sql file I replace all the old urls with new ones.

You should find more info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Actually i used demo import option. And domain1.com is not mine. its for demo only. I developed everything in domain2.com. Still i need to change in database or is there any other settings  i can change?

Comment: Can you tell us the name of the theme? Or what plugin is used for importing the demo settings?

Answer (score 0):

In the database for domain2, in wp_options, change siteurl to the new domain. else you could replace manually in the wpconfig file per the codex:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```